# What is the relation between the different generating functions thought as finite approximations of action functionals

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, generating-functions, symplectic-topology, hamiltonian-mechanics, hamiltonian-paths

In the book *Introduction to symplectic topology* by MC Duff and Salamon, a discrete analogue of the action functional is defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. The idea is that a Hamiltonian isotopy can be decomposed into small pieces, such that each one admits a so-called **generating function of type $V$**, which is a kind of analogue of the Hamiltonian function itself, but rather associated with the small piece only, and satisfying a discrete analogue of Hamilton's equations. The discrete action functional is then defined on a space of *discrete trajectories* by means of this generating function and a discrete analogue of the Liouville form. I refer to p.366 of the book for more details (this is pretty involved in terms of details).

On the other hand, Chaperon has defined a generating function by means of the technique of broken trajectories, to prove the Arnold conjecture for the $2n$-torus in a finite-dimensional technical way. Laudenbach and Sikorav have extended his construction to the case of cotangent bundles (I find their article more readable than Chaperon's). In addition to proving a cup length version of the Arnold conjecture, this allowed them to establish the existence of a generating function quadratic at infinity for any Hamiltonian deformation of the zero section of a cotangent bundle (over a closed manifold).

In Mc Duff and Salamon's book, it is said that Chaperon's generating function and the discrete action functional are the same (p.363). I would like to know if by any chance, someone could help me understand why this is true.

The edition of Mc Duff and Salamon's book I am talking about is the last one, edition 2017.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This relationship is discussed in Section 1.4.4 of **Discrete Mechanics and Variational Integrators** http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/bib/2001/09-MaWe2001/MaWe2001.pdf  Note that generating functions can be expressed in any local coordinate system and specifically any two of $q_0$, $p_0$, $q_1$ and $p_1$, and each pair leads to generating functions of different types.   The most common choice is probably $q_0$ and $q_1$ (pair of configurations), and in this case, the relation between the generating function and the action is given by Jacobi's solution to the Hamilton-Jacobi PDE in (1.7.1).

Comment: Thanks. Where do you see a similar construction as Chaperon's in these notes ?